# Matching two files

Tags: linux, awk

I want to make a matching between two files on Linux

I have two files:

File1 (3 fields, separated by `|`)

```
M000990520|CAMPOS HORMAZA MIGUEL | 1,725.30
M000990521|MATEO MIGUEL ZENON | 1,143.86
M000990522|HAITI MIRAFLORES | 1,054.81
M000990523|MESIAS FIBIA ELESCANO DE | 826.33
M000990525|DISTRIBUIDORA LUZA S R LTDA DILU | 985.87
M000990526|ZARATE DAVILA GREGORIO | 1,513.10
```

and file2 (1 field):

```
M000990521
M000990523
M010990521
M002990523
M004990521
M004990523
```

I need to make a match and get this:

```
M000990521|MATEO MIGUEL ZENON | 1,143.86
M000990523|MESIAS FIBIA ELESCANO DE | 826.33
```

I tried with this awk command:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1];next}($1 in a){print}' file1 file2
```

Comment: `awk ... file2 file1` should do it.

Comment: this has been asked and answered thousands of times on this forum....

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F'|' 'NR==FNR{A[$1];next}$1 in A' file2 file1

M000990521|MATEO MIGUEL ZENON | 1,143.86
M000990523|MESIAS FIBIA ELESCANO DE | 826.33

grep -wFf file2 file1

M000990521|MATEO MIGUEL ZENON | 1,143.86
M000990523|MESIAS FIBIA ELESCANO DE | 826.33

awk -F'|' 'NR==FNR{c[$1]++;next};c[$1] > 0' file2.txt file1.txt

M000990521|MATEO MIGUEL ZENON | 1,143.86
M000990523|MESIAS FIBIA ELESCANO DE | 826.33

cut -d'|' -f 1 file2.txt | while read pat; do grep "^$pat" file1.txt; done

M000990521|MATEO MIGUEL ZENON | 1,143.86
M000990523|MESIAS FIBIA ELESCANO DE | 826.33
```

Comment: Thank you very much!
But I have executed it and it does not work        [usrpcd@gppesvlcoc0013 ~]$  grep -wFf pru.txt pruebatup.TXTMX01
[usrpcd@gppesvlcoc0013 ~]$  grep -wFf pruebatup.TXTMX01 pru.txt
[usrpcd@gppesvlcoc0013 ~]$
[usrpcd@gppesvlcoc0013 ~]$
[usrpcd@gppesvlcoc0013 ~]$
[usrpcd@gppesvlcoc0013 ~]$
[usrpcd@gppesvlcoc0013 ~]$ awk -F'|' 'NR==FNR{A[$1];next}$1 in A' pru.txt pruebatup.TXTMX01
[usrpcd@gppesvlcoc0013 ~]$ awk -F'|' 'NR==FNR{A[$1];next}$1 in A' pruebatup.TXTMX01 pru.txt

Comment: what is your `OS`

Comment: [usrpcd@gppesvlcoc0013 ~]$ uname
Linux
[usrpcd@gppesvlcoc0013 ~]$ cat /etc/issue
\S
Kernel \r on an \m

Initial login with linux:lgQ$j$3kM

Comment: try `which awk` to get the `awk` version or try removing line endings from your input using `dod2unix` or `tr -d '\r' <input >output`. Do you get any error messages, I used `ubuntu 14.04` and `cygwin` and all 4 commands work.